# Double animated Path drawing bug, with Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, raphael

I'm using a custom found **function to draw path**, in order to draw a logo with animations (using jquery and Raphael.js). This "animateLine" function is usefull since it draws a svg  path considering FX, along the "vector" path. For just one path there is no problem with this function (It can be found in the demo ).

```
function animateLine (canvas, hoverDivName, colorNumber, pathString, duration, destination)
```

The problem is that there is some kind of **conflict** when using that **function simultaneously** (Drawing 2 path at the same time).

You can see **my problem here on this fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/VyRDk/2/

I thought the issue was the conflict with the temporary var "*destination*", but i'm using 2 diffrent globals vars when calling "AnimateLine" function (you'll notice "lepathanimated1" and "lepathanimated2")

```
var lepathanimated1;
var lepathanimated2;
```

Used this way :

```
animateLine(logo_animated, "canvas", "#1d1d1b", path_circle,1200,lepathanimated1);
```

I hope you have enough information to maybe find the solution, and if you need more details, just ask =)

Thanks for your time

**EDIT:** OMG i just found the solution!! #SoHappy

I just created the path object outside the function and used an identifier (# id) to avoid the conflict (and used it for the jquery animate step function)

You can find the correct **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/VyRDk/5/)**

**HOWEVER** I'm not shure that's the right way to do that (optimisation). Using "animate" in spite of "RequestAnimFram" is it correct? The advantage is having Raphael & jQuery working together (easier that javascript canvas way)

Anyway, hopping it helps =)

PS : **If it helped please vote up**, cos' that's my first stackoverflow question/answer and still 1 of reputation -_-

Answer (score 0):

Here you go [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VyRDk/3/)

You had to adjust `setTimeout` so that it starts right after the first path is drawn.

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    animateLine(logo_animated, "canvas2", "#1d1d1b", 
                path_trait_sup,1200,lepathanimated2);
},1200);
```

Good Luck

Comment: I know, but i need the drawings to be simultaneous (so the animation is not boring) =)

Thanks for trying ^^

Comment: Oh, i did not read the commented part in your demo. So I see what do you mean now. I will look at it but cannot promise the answer